# Show every post inside category (controllers, routing and views interaction)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have simple blog app with posts, comments and so on and wanna add categorization to posts, i.e. every post belongs to only one category and inside it post showed.

Now inside routes

```
resources :category do
  resources :posts
end
```

I wanna paths like

> category/job

I generate CategoryController, but how to fill it and chain with already existing posts controller?

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @category = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])  
  end

end
```

Also how could be views looks like of categories so that inside it showed posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your place I would leave posts and categories as separate resources. Like:

```
resources :posts
resources :categories, only: [:show]
```

Then your route category/job will actually be a simple #show action which you could implement like

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @posts    = @category.posts
  end
end
```

In order to achieve the "job" to be an id inside the url in the Category model you should add something like

```
class Category < Active
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

This way you will keep your resources clean and simple and not introduce unnecessary complexity.